Im unable to filter records using getListRecordsByName and GraphQL - Im getting MALFORMED_QUERY
Im using getListRecordsByName API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-get-list-records-by-name.html
This works perfectly fine
@wire(getListRecordsByName, {
    listViewApiName: '$selectedListView1',
    objectApiName: 'ServiceAppointment',
    pageToken: '$pageToken',
    fields: '$fields',
    where: '{ ServiceTerritory: { Name: { in: ["Tel Aviv","Los Angeled"] } } } ] }'
  })

But this does not
 @wire(getListRecordsByName, {
    listViewApiName: '$selectedListView1',
    objectApiName: 'ServiceAppointment',
    pageToken: '$pageToken',
    fields: '$fields',
    where: '{ ServiceTerritory: { Id: { in: ["001xx000003GYQxAAO","001xx000003GYQxAA1"] } } } ] }'
  })

Why?
Error: {
  "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "body": {
      "message": "We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help.\nError ID: 2082124199-117233 (-1629978171)",
      "statusCode": 400,
      "enhancedErrorType": "RecordError",
      "output": {
        "errors": [
          {
            "constituentField": null,
            "duplicateRecordError": null,
            "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION",
            "field": null,
            "fieldLabel": null,
            "message": "ui.services.connection.api.PartnerConnectionException: MALFORMED_QUERY: \nWHERE ServiceTerritory.Id in (001xx000003GYQxAAO','001xx000003GYQxAA1)\n                                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:367\nmissing value at 'xx000003GYQxAAO'"
          }
        ],
        "fieldErrors": {}
      },
      "id": "-619637776"
    },
    "headers": {},
    "ok": false,
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "errorType": "fetchResponse"
  }
}

Thank you!

The error is because of the extra "}" in where.
The where looks like this: where: '{ ServiceTerritory: { Id: { in: ["001xx000003GYQxAAO", "001xx000003GYQxAA1"] } } }' 
@wire(getListRecordsByName, {
        listViewApiName: '$selectedListView1',
        objectApiName: 'ServiceAppointment',
        pageToken: '$pageToken',
        fields: '$fields',
        where: '{ ServiceTerritory: { Id: { in: ["001xx000003GYQxAAO", "001xx000003GYQxAA1"] } } }'
})


The third "} is there to close the first "{"
This works without issue
where: '{ ServiceTerritory: { Name: { in: ["NameA","NameB"] } } } ] }'


That does not work
